# What is the problem with my JS function searching html classes and conditionally hiding or showing?

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I am trying to modify a Dawn 2.0 theme to, on the product page, only render images with certain tags depending on an input selector. I have one product which consists of 8 items, each item has an image. This product can be ordered in three variations:

- The first variation would be the product with 4 items.
- The second variation would be the product with 6 items.
- The third variation would be the product with 8 items.

There is a variant selector in the products page:

[image]

and the three variants have been created on the Shopify admin products page. The solution that I'm attempting to use is [this](https://youtu.be/ARpSIscriYA) one. I chose it as it's the only one I found reference to elsewhere (apart from buying an add on which I don't want to do), it seemed a logical approach to me, though I have no particular loyalty to this approach if anyone can think of a better way to achieve what I'm trying to.

This solution involves using values assigned to image's alt text attribute via the Shopify admin products page. The alt text values applied are:

1. `set_all` for the first 4 images, because these 4 items would be included in all three of variants (the one with only x4 itmes, the one with x6 items, and the one with x8 items).
2. `set_6&8` for the 5th and 6th images, because these 2 items would be included in both  the 2nd variant (the one with x6 items) and the 3rd variant (the one with x8 items).
3. `set_8` for the 7th and 8th images, because these 2 items would only be included in the 3rd variant (the one with x8 items)

Then interpolating that alt text value into a data tag in the html:

```
data-thumbnail-set-number="{{media.alt}}"
```

which is applied to the `<li>` that each image is housed within and then writing a js function which:

1. hides all images
2. stores in local variable the alt text value of the featured image ('featured image' being the one, and only, image that you can apply to each variant in the Shopify admin products page. Therefore if the user selects a different variant a different featured image with different alt text is attached to that variant).
3. shows the images whose `data-thumbnail-set-number` value matches the value from the variant's featured_image.alt text. JS  being:

'./assets/global.js' in `VariantSelects` class, line ~561

```
onVariantChange() {
   ...
   this.filterThumbnails();
   ...
};

filterThumbnails() {
    if (this.currentVariant.featured_media != null && this.currentVariant.featured_media.alt != null) {
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-thumbnail-set-number]').forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
      });
    // show thumbnails for selected set
      var selected_set = this.currentVariant.featured_media.alt;
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-thumbnail-set-number="' + selected_set + '"]').forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
      });
    }
    else {
    //show all thumbnails
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-thumbnail-set-number]').forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
      });
    }
    // console.log("thumbnail update", this.currentVariant.featured_media.alt)
  }
```

This all works apart from two problems:

1. I need to write further conditions in the JS to not just match the featured_image.alt text but to also include:

- the `set_all` images as those items come with all 3 variations, and for the set_8 variant to include the `set_6&8` images. I should be able to deal with this fine, will probably hard code the `data-thumbnail-set-number` that each three conditional is looking for.

2. Even though the JS function seems to be effective at searching and showing the images with a `data-thumbnail-set-number` value that matches the variant's featured image alt text value, the page also always seems to render one other image, which does not have the `data-thumbnail-set-number` class applied to the `<li>` at all, and it seems that that image is always the first of the images saved to the main product.

Despite a good deal of time looking I can't seem to understand why issue 2. is happening, and how to stop it. Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: I've had better luck asking this kind of question on the Shopify forums. As a solution to #2, during the "show thumbnails for selected set" logic you could get the parent element of a li with `data-thumbnail-set-number` class, and then hide set `display: none` on any children that don't have the class. I'm not familiar with that theme in particular, but this should work. It would require you to change the "show all thumbnails" to set `display: block` on all children of the parent too.

Comment: Thanks @yuuuu, that's helpful. As you were writing this I was writing my own answer as I found the problem was with me not seeing two separate `<li>`'s being rendered in the main-product.liquid. Which is the Shopify forum that you find most responsive for these types of things?

Comment: The specific forum I tend to use is https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/bd-p/ecommerce-design - it can be a little hit or miss, but generally the response rate is much higher than here where most users don't have experience with shopify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEBCAK

To solve issue 2, I found that another `<li>` is inserted in the `main-product.liquid` above the `<li>` which iterates and shows all images in the image colleciton just to show just the featured image. I don't really understand why this featured image is separated out for rendering apart from the others in the collection, but it it. I just needed to add the `data-thumbnail-set-number="{{media.alt}}"` into this newly found featured image `<li>`.

As i took some time to write out this question I thought that I'd leave it here in case it's of help to anyone else.